# Finding the area under array with x and y data divided into n groups in numpy/python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, area, integral

If I have an array with x and y data that is divided into 20 groups, how would I find the area under each group?

For simplicity, consider

```
x=np.linspace(1,100,100)
y=a
c=np.vstack((x,y)).T
```

this is just the line y=x with 100 points for x and y. If I use trapz(b,a) I get an approximate area under the line.

Now I want to divide this into 20 groups and find the area under each group

```
d=np.array_split(temprange,20)
```

How do I find the area in each group. Each group should have 5 x points and 5 y points and I want to use trapz to find the area of each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this w/out relying too much on np, although the `array_split` is a great tool. Basically the code splits the xs and ys separately, then combines them with zip to make for easy indexing.

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(1,100,100)
y = x

#Split x's and y's separately then combine them w/ zip
num_groups = 20
split_xs = np.array_split(x,num_groups)
split_ys = np.array_split(y,num_groups)
split_groups = zip(split_xs,split_ys)

#Short version w/ list comprehension
split_trapzs = [np.trapz(split_y,split_x) for split_x,split_y in split_groups]

#Longer version w/out list comprehension
split_trapzs = []
for split_x,split_y in split_groups:
    split_trapz = np.trapz(split_y,split_x)
    print 'x:',split_x,'y:',split_x,'trapz:',split_trapz
    split_trapzs.append(split_trapz)

print 'Split trapzs:',split_trapzs
```

OUTPUT:

```
x: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.] y: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.] trapz: 12.0
x: [  6.   7.   8.   9.  10.] y: [  6.   7.   8.   9.  10.] trapz: 32.0
x: [ 11.  12.  13.  14.  15.] y: [ 11.  12.  13.  14.  15.] trapz: 52.0
x: [ 16.  17.  18.  19.  20.] y: [ 16.  17.  18.  19.  20.] trapz: 72.0
x: [ 21.  22.  23.  24.  25.] y: [ 21.  22.  23.  24.  25.] trapz: 92.0
x: [ 26.  27.  28.  29.  30.] y: [ 26.  27.  28.  29.  30.] trapz: 112.0
x: [ 31.  32.  33.  34.  35.] y: [ 31.  32.  33.  34.  35.] trapz: 132.0
x: [ 36.  37.  38.  39.  40.] y: [ 36.  37.  38.  39.  40.] trapz: 152.0
x: [ 41.  42.  43.  44.  45.] y: [ 41.  42.  43.  44.  45.] trapz: 172.0
x: [ 46.  47.  48.  49.  50.] y: [ 46.  47.  48.  49.  50.] trapz: 192.0
x: [ 51.  52.  53.  54.  55.] y: [ 51.  52.  53.  54.  55.] trapz: 212.0
x: [ 56.  57.  58.  59.  60.] y: [ 56.  57.  58.  59.  60.] trapz: 232.0
x: [ 61.  62.  63.  64.  65.] y: [ 61.  62.  63.  64.  65.] trapz: 252.0
x: [ 66.  67.  68.  69.  70.] y: [ 66.  67.  68.  69.  70.] trapz: 272.0
x: [ 71.  72.  73.  74.  75.] y: [ 71.  72.  73.  74.  75.] trapz: 292.0
x: [ 76.  77.  78.  79.  80.] y: [ 76.  77.  78.  79.  80.] trapz: 312.0
x: [ 81.  82.  83.  84.  85.] y: [ 81.  82.  83.  84.  85.] trapz: 332.0
x: [ 86.  87.  88.  89.  90.] y: [ 86.  87.  88.  89.  90.] trapz: 352.0
x: [ 91.  92.  93.  94.  95.] y: [ 91.  92.  93.  94.  95.] trapz: 372.0
x: [  96.   97.   98.   99.  100.] y: [  96.   97.   98.   99.  100.] trapz: 392.0
Split trapzs: [12.0, 32.0, 52.0, 72.0, 92.0, 112.0, 132.0, 152.0, 172.0, 192.0, 212.0, 232.0, 252.0, 272.0, 292.0, 312.0, 332.0, 352.0, 372.0, 392.0]
```

Comment: fantastic! thank you. I will try a variation of this on what I need and hopefully it works.

Comment: great, feel free to update your question if you run into more problems